# How to tell what optimizations bjam is using to build boost

Tags: c++, boost, bjam

I'm building the boost libraries with bjam for both the intel compiler and vs2008, and I can't tell what optimizations are being passed to the compiler from bjam. For one of the compiler's gcc, I can see some optimizations in one of the bjam files, but I can't find the optimization flags for the compilers I care about. So, my questions are -

1. Does anyone know where the default optimization flags are located?
2. If they're declared within bjam, does anyone know how I can override them?

Comment: a lot of libraries are header-only, are you concerned about optimization of a particular library, threads for example?

Comment: check out this question, it should answer you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722421/how-to-determine-value-of-cxxflags-in-bjam-or-append-to-it

Comment: I'm concerned with boost::gregorian::date which is partially a static library

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are interested in looking at the entire set of options that are passed to invoke the compiler when building you can run `bjam` with the `-n -a` options and the rest of the building options to give you the complete set of commands invoked, and any response files generated (see [Boost Jam Options](https://boostorg.github.io/build/manual/develop/index.html#bbv2.overview.invocation.options)). Also you can look at the Boost Build sources directly and see what the specified features are translated into (see [Boost Build Tools Files](https://github.com/boostorg/build/tree/master/src/tools)). For example:

- For GCC see [gcc.jam](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/master/src/tools/gcc.jam)
- For MSVC see [msvc.jam](https://github.com/boostorg/build/blob/master/src/tools/msvc.jam)

You can likely figure out the same for other compilers by just looking through the sources as they are fairly self explanatory. And you can just search for "`<optimization>`" and "`<inlining>`" in the `*.jam` sources.

You can override them in the command line by specifying the `feature=value` option in the command line when building. The options match the `<feature>value` specifications you see in the toolset files. For example, to override the optimizations feature you would specify in the command line some like `"optimization=speed"`. If you want more fine grained control you would have to delve into Boost Build specifications and likely have to create a variant of your own to define specific options and features to build with.

Comment: All links are broken!

Comment: Thank you @val -- I've updated the links to latest docs and code.