# how to add a new compiler switch in bjam

Tags: c++, managed, bjam

I need to compile a library in managed c++ and looking into msvc.jam, I cannot find any feature that would add the /clr switch to my compile flags.

How would I add such a feature?
If possible, I would like to avoid modifying msvc.jam.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The makefile macro you want for compiler flags is CXXFLAGS, and its equivalent on the bjam command line is cxxflags (lower case):

```
bjam toolset=msvc cxxflags=/clr
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using the command line, here's what I came up with:

import feature ;

feature.feature managed
    :
        off
        on
    :
        composite 
        propagated
        link-incompatible
    ;

feature.compose <managed>on
    :
        <asynch-exceptions>on
        <cxxflags>/clr
    ;

Comment: Obviously you were willing to delve deeper into the build system and its documentation than I was. cxxflags worked for me, so I settled on that and then got out of there quickly before I broke anything!

Answer (score 0):

Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2722421/how-to-determine-value-of-cxxflags-in-bjam-or-append-to-it) thread? I think it can help.